# How can I reuse multiple zipfileset elements in Ant?

Tags: ant, zip, fileset

We want to build multiple zip files where some of the files have contents in common with others. Rather than specify the full list of files for each zip (they're actually quite large) I thought I would try to get some reuse.

So I tried using `<union>` for this:

```
<project name="test" default="zips">
  <target name="zips">
    <union id="common">
      <zipfileset prefix="." dir="." includes="1"/>
      <zipfileset prefix="3" dir="." includes="2"/>
    </union>
    <zip zipfile="1.zip">
      <resources refid="common"/>
    </zip>
    <zip zipfile="2.zip">
      <resources refid="common"/>
    </zip>
  </target>
</project>
```

This does generate two zip files with "1" and "2" inside each, but the "3" prefix is missing from both files.

What am I doing wrong?

We also have a custom task which uses zipfileset internally. I tried to get it to work with union as well, but couldn't figure out how to get at the prefix value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your `common` resourcecollection:

```
<union id="common">
  <fileset dir="." includes="1"/>
  <mappedresources>
      <fileset dir="." includes="2"/>
      <globmapper from="*" to="3/*"/>
  </mappedresources>
</union>
```

The `prefix` parameter in a `zipfileset` is only used when reading files from an archive specified with the `src` parameter, otherwise it is ignored - which is the behaviour you see.
For your use, you are trying to specify the prefix in the created archive.  To do that you need a mapper.

*See also: Ant docs for [`mappedresources.`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources)*

Comment: Interesting. So I guess this is a bit of a gotcha. <zipfileset> inside <zip> does use the prefix, but I went to have a look and it seems that the zip task explicitly looks for it and converts it into a mapper.

Comment: Only one catch implementing it in practice - I can't figure out how to derive the location of the file from a Resource object in our custom task. :)